# Running on iOS 7.1 simulator brings errors in the console output

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.9.3 on Mac with Mono 4.0.1, Xcode 6.3.2 and Xamarin.iOS 8.10.1.64. When I try to run my app in the iOS 7.1 simulator I get the following console output:

```
objc[1102]: Class AXEmojiUtilities is implemented in both /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities and /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libAXSpeechManager.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2015-06-22 09:25:43.395 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7869e5f0 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GameKitFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.434 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x786a4760 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/StoreKitFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.435 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78dbe9f0 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/iAdFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.438 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x786aca20 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/EventKitUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.439 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78dc2270 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.441 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78dc7620 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SocialFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.442 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78dc8120 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/PassKitFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.443 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78dc8ab0 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/TwitterFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.448 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78dca6c0 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MusicLibrary.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.458 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78c134c0 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GameCenterUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.459 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78c12a50 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/RemoteUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.491 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78f64520 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle> (not loaded)
2015-06-22 09:25:43.500 SomeApp[1102:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x78f7c600 </Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/StoreKitUI.axbundle> (not loaded)
```

What I'm doing wrong? The simulator is running fine, but those error messages are annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubymotion/BJahVGR2pSw).

> iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings

Now I don't have the error messages anymore. You should be aware that all installed apps are gone after this action!